# How to extend Crystal language syntax?

Tags: macros, crystal-lang

For example, i want to get looks-like-native "for" loop, which was implemented in crystal's embedded macro language, but it is absent (for reasons of principle) in main, "runtime" language:

```
for i in list do
end

for k, v in hash do
end
```

(Here "{}" is a simple block. I cant use do .. end syntax here anyway (maybe not)).
Will be very good to implement multi-inlcude directive, such as:

```
includes MixinX, MixinY, MixinZ
```

and so on...
As i know, macro (named "for" and "includes" in the provided snippets) can't accept "i in list" without double-quoting. So... is there only one way to do so - extending crystal's syntax/lexical parser and analyzer itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, you could use something like this:

```
module Foo
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
end

module Bar
  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

class Object
  macro includes(*mods)
    {% for mod in mods %}
      include  {{ mod }}
      {% end %}
  end
end

class Baz
  includes Foo, Bar
end

Baz.new.foo # => "foo"
Baz.new.bar # => "bar"
```

Comment: Yeah, of course, *mods! Its really wonderful :) And what about for? Could it be implemented using macroses?

Comment: @drvtiny I don't know a way to do that, sorry. And personally I wouldn't do that, because I can't see any advantage of using `for`, as we have `each` already.

Comment: I dont need "for" operator itself, i am wonder if it is possible to "emulate" normal native syntax using macroses, such as: "my_macro space separated phrase". I think, this can be done with some kind of preprocessing like "filtering" in perl, but this is very unlikely to be implemented in Crystal some day... Thank you very much for your answer i'll mark it as a resolution. Good luck! :)

Comment: @drvtiny oh, sorry for misunderstanding. The difficulty of implementing an operator will be individual. As you can see, it was pretty easy to implement `includes`, but we can think of "syntactical constructions" (especially multiline ones) that would be tricky to implement without changing Crystal internals.
P.S. I'm not a big expert of Crystal, so as your question is not quite answered, maybe it worth to uncheck it as a right answer to grab attention of other more experienced users. :)